# Combining 1200 csv files in r with different column numbers

Tags: r, csv

I need to combine 1200 csv files into one but they have multiple columns.  Newbie her:  Upon searching through the forums, I've decided that my code should look something like this:

```
list.files()
filenames <- list.files(path = "~/")
do.call("rbind.fill", lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

When I run this, I don't receive anything but:  NULL

Any ideas for me to be able to output one large csv file that combines all of these would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your "filenames" should be empty. Be sure list.files find any files in the folder you specified.

Excerpt from rbind.fill documentation:

Arguments
... 
input data frames to row bind together. The first argument can be a list of data frames, in which case all other arguments are ignored. Any NULL inputs are silently dropped. **If all inputs are NULL, the output is NULL**

Comment: I think that worked but how do I get it to output a new csv file as part of this script?  Can I add a write.csv command somewhere within the code?

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks.